# Help identifing a 6-pin SMD IC, code AS202

Tags: identification, surface-mount

I was wondering if anyone can help me with identifying 6-pin IC with marking code AS202. It’s part of an Android box. There are four of them on the board; one of them burned and needs to be replaced.

[image]

Comment: According to [here](https://www.s-manuals.com/smd/as), the IC is [this](https://www.richtek.com/assets/product_file/RT9011/DS9011-09.pdf). However, looking at the layout, I can't be sure because, even if pin-1 and pin-2 look like outputs as shown in the datasheet pin-3 and pin-4 have large copper pours so they don't look like EN inputs.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's probably a [Silergy SY8009 Buck Regulator](https://www.s-manuals.com/pdf/datasheet/s/y/sy8009a%2C_sy8009b_r1.0_silergy.pdf).
The pinout seems to match your PCB layout:
[image]
with the inductor on pin-3, an input filter/storage cap on pin-4, etc.